# show all system's files and folders in jtree

Tags: java, netbeans-7, jtree

I am new to java development
I am trying to display all the drives of system including all files and folders.
This code is working fine but only display the single directory or drive.
how i can make it display all the drives on my system's including folders and files.
Thanks in advance.

/// Implementation to display specific directory   (Currently using netbeans)

```
     jTree1.setModel(new FileSystemModel(new File("Director Path to display")));
```

//FileSystemModel

```
public class FileSystemModel implements TreeModel {
private File root;
private Vector listeners = new Vector();

public FileSystemModel(File rootDirectory) 
{        
   root = rootDirectory;
}

@Override
public Object getRoot() {

    return root;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    String[] children = directory.list();


    return new FileSystemModel.TreeFile(directory, children[index]);
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
    File file = (File) parent;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        String[] fileList = file.list();

        if (fileList != null) {
            return file.list().length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
    File file = (File) node;
    return file.isFile();
}

@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
    File directory = (File) parent;
    File file = (File) child;
    String[] children = directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (file.getName().equals(children[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}

@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object value) {
    File oldFile = (File) path.getLastPathComponent();
    String fileParentPath = oldFile.getParent();
    String newFileName = (String) value;
    File targetFile = new File(fileParentPath, newFileName);
    oldFile.renameTo(targetFile);
    File parent = new File(fileParentPath);
    int[] changedChildrenIndices = {getIndexOfChild(parent, targetFile)};
    Object[] changedChildren = {targetFile};
    fireTreeNodesChanged(path.getParentPath(), changedChildrenIndices,     changedChildren);

}

private void fireTreeNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices, Object[] children) {
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices, children);
    Iterator iterator = listeners.iterator();
    TreeModelListener listener = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        listener = (TreeModelListener) iterator.next();
        listener.treeNodesChanged(event);
    }
}

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

private class TreeFile extends File {

    public TreeFile(File parent, String child) {
        super(parent, child);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the entire tree, you need to recognize when one of the children is itself a directory and gather its contents as well. It looks like you'd want to do that in the method you're calling `getChild` (getChildren would be a better name for it).